# Replicate a box using fancybox

Tags: boxes

[image]

As the title says, is there a way to do this by using the fancybox features?
I'd really like to know if it's possible.

Also, what's the font written in the text? Is there a way to replicate it?

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I's suggest you [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{100,22,72}

\newtcolorbox{learn}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colframe=titlebg,
  colback=titlebg!05,
  overlay unbroken and first={
    \node[
      draw=titlebg,
      fill=titlebg,
      rotate=270,
      anchor=north west,
      text=white,
      font=\bfseries
    ]
    at (frame.north west)  
    {LEARN THIS};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{learn}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{learn}

\end{document}
```

Regarding the fonts part of the question, please see [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/3954).

Comment: AMAZING!! I just added another question in the main post! Thank you!

Comment: @Oshnaj Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Oshnaj You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: @Oshnaj Sure I can help you, but this is not the way this place works. We try to keep one question per post, so please undo the last edit and open a new question with the new request.

Comment: You can now see it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253263/replicate-a-box-part-2

Comment: @Oshnaj And now there's an answer there :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25456/discussion-between-oshnaj-and-gonzalo-medina).