# Replicate a box | Part 2

Tags: boxes

You can follow part 1 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253220/replicate-a-box-using-fancybox/%20here).

As for part 2, I'd like to know how to replicate the image you see below.

[image]

Comment: I did not vote you down, but I suspect that the community is not happy with your question because it shows no effort on your part, and expects those who might help you to do all the work.  Generally, it is expected that you will have attempted something in the direction of a solution and post that complete bit of code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how to make it. If I knew the slighest idea how to make it, I would've posted it. Besides, I don't even know if I can modify the code of the other answer, it's way too complex for me, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @Oshnaj — Have you tried reading the manual for tcolorbox, which was suggested for your first question? I opened it up and skimmed over it very quickly, and it seemed to offer some helpful tools for this kind of thing.

Comment: @WillRobertson And in response to the OP's [earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243768/box-with-fancy-colors). There is something of a pattern here, perhaps...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `raster` library:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{194,103,14}
\definecolor{subtitlebg}{RGB}{225,125,0}

\newtcolorbox{verbs}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=1pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  toptitle=3pt,
  lefttitle=4mm,
  bottomtitle=3pt,
  colbacktitle=titlebg,
  colframe=titlebg,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\itshape\bfseries,
  title=\strut #2,
  #1
}

\newcommand\MyVerb[5]{%
\begin{verbs}{#1}
\begin{tcbitemize}[
  boxsep=0pt,
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  colframe=subtitlebg,
  halign=left,
  valign=top,
  arc=5mm,
  raster width=\textwidth,
  raster column skip=0pt,
  raster row skip=0pt,
  raster halign=center,
  raster valign=top,
  raster equal height=rows,
  toptitle=2pt,
  bottomtitle=1pt,
  ]
\tcbitem[rightrule=0.4pt,leftrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily affirmative]
  #2
\tcbitem[leftrule=0.4pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily negative]
  #3
\tcbitem[rightrule=0.4pt,leftrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily interrogative]
  #4
\tcbitem[leftrule=0.4pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily short answers]
  #5
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{verbs}%
}

\begin{document}

\MyVerb{be}
  {Some test text goes here to see the alignment when line breaks are present.}
  {Some test text}
  {Some test text}
  {\begin{enumerate}
    \item A test list.
    \item Second.
    \item Third.
    \end{enumerate}
  }

\end{document}
```

The main command is `\MyVerb` with five mandatory arguments:

```
\MyVerb{<general title>}{<text for box1>}{<text for box3>}{<text for box3>}{<text for box4>}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to push the word "affirmative" in your code but I don't see what I need to change.

Comment: @Oshnaj What do you mean by "push"? Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: I mean move the text to the right or left.

Comment: @Oshnaj to move it a fixed length, you can use `lefttitle`, as in `\tcbitem[lefttitle=2cm,rightrule=0.4pt,leftrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily affirmative]` (or `righttitle`). To center it: `\tcbitem[center title,rightrule=0.4pt,leftrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,title=\strut\bfseries\sffamily affirmative]`

Answer (score 2):

Without `tcolorbox`, since this is a simple colored table:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\arrayrulecolor{red!25!yellow}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{5cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{red!60!yellow}\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\color{white}be}\\\hline
\rowcolor{red!40!yellow}\color{white}affirmative &\color{white}affirmative\\\hline
\rowcolor{white}
Bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots
& 
Bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots
\\\hline
\rowcolor{red!40!yellow}    \color{white}interrogative & \color{white}short answers\\\hline
Bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
& 
Bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
Bla bla bla \rule{1cm}{1pt} \ldots\par
\\\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```